# エラー: 列名の重複を避けるためにはカーソルのSELECTリストに別名が必要です

Tags: sql

PL/SQLのカーソルを使ってSQLをjoinして挿入しようとすると「列名の重複を避けるためにはカーソルのSELECTリストに別名が必要です。」とエラーが出ます。なぜなのでしょうか？
下の部分が何か間違っているのでしょうか？

```
r_ABC c_ABC%ROWTYPE;  -- SELECTで取得したレコードを代入する変数の定義
v_CNT NUMBER:= 0;

    BEGIN
        OPEN c_ABC;
        　　LOOP
            FETCH c_ABC INTO r_ABC;
            EXIT WHEN c_ABC%NOTFOUND;
                v_CNT := v_CNT + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

質問文のコードではなく`c_ABC`で記述しているselect文が間違っている可能性があります。

今回ご質問のエラーはOracleの`PLS-00402`かと思います。
[Oracleのドキュメント](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E82638_01/errmg/PLS-00049.html)では該当エラーについて下記のように書かれています。

> PLS-00402: 列名の重複を避けるためにはカーソルのSELECTリストに別名が必要です。
> 原因: 重複する列名を含むSELECT文でカーソルが宣言されています。この参照は、不明確です。
> 処置: SELECTリストで重複している列名を別名で置き換えてください。

上記の通りカーソルのselect文で同一の列名を取得しようとすると、不明確な参照としてエラーが発生します。
カーソルに使用する列名は重複しないように別名を定義してみてください。

下記はNGとOKになるストアドのサンプルコードです。
5行目をコメント化して7行目のコメントを削除するとコンパイルが通ります。

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST00402
IS
  CURSOR c_ABC IS
      -- NGなSELECT文
      SELECT  a.val, b.val
      -- OKなSELECT文
   -- SELECT  a.val as a_val, b.val as b_val
        FROM  (select 1 idx, 'hoge' val  from dual) a
             ,(select 1 idx, 'fuga' val  from dual) b
        WHERE  a.idx = b.idx;
  r_ABC  c_ABC%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  OPEN c_ABC;
  LOOP
    FETCH c_ABC INTO r_ABC;
    EXIT WHEN c_ABC%NOTFOUND;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE c_ABC;
END;
/
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。エラーがまだ解決できず、joinする項目が1対多になっているのでダメみたいです。。

Answer (score -2):

エラーメッセージ「列名の重複を避けるためにはカーソルのSELECTリストに別名が必要です。」は、通常、カーソル内のSELECT文で同じ名前の列が複数回参照されている場合に発生します。これは、FETCH文でデータを取り出すときに、同じ名前の変数が複数の列に対して使われる可能性があるためです。

提供されたコードの部分からは、具体的なSELECT文が見当たりませんが、このエラーが発生する主な原因として以下のいくつかが考えられます：

SELECT文で同じ列名が複数回使われている：

sql
Copy code
SELECT column1, column2, column1 FROM your_table;
このように同じ列が複数回出てくる場合、カーソルのFETCH文でそれらの列をどの変数に代入するかが曖昧になります。この場合、ASキーワードを使用して列に別名を付けることで解決できます。

sql
Copy code
SELECT column1, column2, column1 AS alias_column FROM your_table;
カーソルのSELECTリストに同じ名前の変数が複数回存在する：
カーソルを開いた後、FETCH文でデータを取り出すときに同じ名前の変数が複数の列に対して使われている可能性があります。FETCH文の直前にカーソル内で宣言した変数名がもう一度使用されていないか確認してください。

提供されたコードからは詳細が分かりませんが、カーソル内のSELECT文やFETCH文において同じ名前の列や変数が複数回参照されている可能性があります。具体的なSELECT文とFETCH文を確認して、それぞれの変数が適切に代入されているか確認してみてください。